# Wordpress Conditional Login Links

Tags: login, links

I am simply trying to add conditional Woocommerce login links to a widget area. I need help identifying my code issues. I would like it to Welcome the user in the initial conditional statement but didn't get that far.

```
<div class="account_links">
    <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo <a href="/my-account/" title="My Account Page">MY ACCOUNT</a>
        <span> | </span>
        <a href="/my-account/customer-logout/">LOGOUT</a>} 
    else {
       echo <a href="/my-account/" title="Login Page">LOGIN</a>
        <span> | </span>
        <a href="/my-account" title="Create an Account">REGISTER</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing quotation marks, closing tags, almost everything:

```
<div class="account_links">
    <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<a href="/my-account/" title="My Account Page">MY ACCOUNT</a>
        <span> | </span>
        <a href="/my-account/customer-logout/">LOGOUT</a>'; 
    } else {
       echo '<a href="/my-account/" title="Login Page">LOGIN</a>
        <span> | </span>
        <a href="/my-account" title="Create an Account">REGISTER</a>';
     } ?>
</div>
```

that should do it.

Comment: The OP also should understand that those pages and endpoints can be changed by the client, so hard coding is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunatley, that did not work. It returned MY ACCOUNT | LOGOUT} else{ echo LOGIN | REGISTER

Comment: Make sure you are not logged in

Comment: can you edit your question with the code of where you are putting this? i think you are missing `quotation marks` are you using an IDE?